# IText 7 PDF returns blank page in Production but able to see contents in localhost

Tags: java, pdf, spring-boot, itext7

I have been facing this peculiar issue where the downloaded PDF doesnt have any content , its completely blank but the page count is correct. Here's the code that is used to send the response from the Service.

```
@GET
@RequestMapping(value = "generatePDF/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte []> getPDFInfo(
        @PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception { 
    ByteArrayOutputStream myPDFDetails = pdfService.getPDFInfo(id);

    byte[] myPDFByte=myPDFDetails.toByteArray();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myPDFByte,headers, myPDFByte == null ? HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT : HttpStatus.OK );}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Usually this is a problem known as "byte-shaving." Some servers serve PDF as if they were ASCII files in which case the structure is kept intact (the PDF opens and shows a blank page because the page tree can be read correctly), but the binary content is corrupted (the compressed content stream of each page can no longer be read). If this diagnosis is correct, then this is not an iText problem, but a server configuration problem: your server doesn't know how to serve binary data.

Comment: So it means that its Server specific and not something caused by the above code ? @BrunoLowagie

Comment: You code works on the localhost, but not in production. That is an indication that the code is OK, and that something else is causing the problem. Please do the following test: create a PDF on the localhost, and then create the same PDF in production. Compare both PDF's in a text editor. I think that one PDF will show binary data between `stream`/`endstream` keywords; the other one won't show binary data because the binary file was served as if it were an ASCII file.